# How can get a valid class in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, class, error-handling, routes

In my User.php I have the following Route:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
```

But I get an error in my log file:

```
Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): The \"App\\Entity\\User\" entity has a repositoryClass set to \"App\\Repository\\UserRepository\", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with \"doctrine.repository_service\". at /Users/work/project/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:85, RuntimeException(code: 0): The \"App\\Entity\\User\" entity has a repositoryClass set to \"App\\Repository\\UserRepository\", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with \"doctrine.repository_service\". at /Users/work/project/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Repository/ContainerRepositoryFactory.php:71)"} []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If App\Repository\UserRepository.php doesn't exist.
Either create a valid repository class there, or remove that annotation from the entity if you don't need one.

If the file does exist then perhaps the filename or class definition the the file has a typo, e.g. wrong capital somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, the file "UserRepository.php" was missing. I created it. The error message is gone. But now I get another error: Access Denied. AccessDeniedHttpException

Comment: `Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException: "Access Denied." at /Users/work/project/vendor/symfony/security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php line 68`

Answer (score 0):

I moved my code from :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ParcCarburantRepository::class)
 */
```

To :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ParcCarburantRepository")
 */
```

It works perfectly , sorry I don't know why .. but It works.

Comment: You probably forget to add the 'use' statement? If you forget the use statement, it will search for Repository class inside the same namespace as the entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Table(name="CommandeLigne")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommandeLigneRepository")
 */
```

To :

```
  /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="CommandeLigne")
 * (repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommandeLigneRepository")
 */
```